# Why does my python return value include previous print text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sh

I have created a small python script which I call from another shell script to calculate average value from the data in a file and I'm returning this average value back to a shell script variable. Here's my code:

```
import sys

def calc():
    output = []
    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    with open(file_path, 'r') as input_stream:
        line = next(input_stream, None)
        while line is not None:
            output.append(float(line.split("\t")[-1]))
            #print(output)
            line = next(input_stream, None)
        line = next(input_stream, None)
    avg = sum(output)/len(output)
    print("Average of all weights = %f kg" % avg)
    return print(avg)

calc()
```

However, when I print the value stored in the shell variable

```
echo "$avgVal"
```

it shows the previous print text as well!

**Average of all weights = 78.22 kg**

**78.22**

Why does this happen? Am I making any mistake in the way it's returning the averaged value? How can I get only 78.22 in the shell variable?

Comment: remove the print statement before the return?

Comment: You told the Python code to print something, so it did.  You also told the shell to print something, so it did too.  It looks to me like the shell printed exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @HenryEcker removing the print statement works okay. But I do want that statement to appear on screen before it is passed on to shell

Comment: @MarkRansom maybe am not following you but no, that's not what I asked shell to print. I asked shell to print what's in the variable 'avgVal', which should store the returned value from python i.e. 78.22 (without the preceding print)

Comment: The only thing that `return avg` statement did was set the value of the `calc()` call on the last line of your script.  You didn't do anything with the value at that point, so you might as well not have had the `return` at all.  You are not, in any sense, returning anything to the shell.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, I realised. There's a mistake in my code that I didn't realise when I posted. I get that output when I return "print(avg)". Updating the description now.

Comment: Since you didn't show how you were setting the value into `avgVal` it was hard to follow what you were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell captures whatever is printed to standard output. Print that message to standard error if you don't want it in `avgVal`.

```
print("Average of all weights = %f kg" % avg, file = sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Okay! That makes sense. Thank you, exactly what I wanted.